# How to work on a laptop with only one monitor and having the laptop closed?

Tags: laptop, external-monitor

I want to close my laptop and still being able to use it with an external monitor. Tried several settings including disabling energy saving mode when closing the laptop.
Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You must find out what power-manager you are using. There you switch off the suspend on lid closing. Try: "cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state" or "cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf"

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you tell us what happens. Does it automatically power off? If so, try going into Settings. This can be found by right clicking on the upper bar. Look for a Power tab and find the settings for Power Saving Options and note that there are separate options for when it is on mains vs on battery. Deselect any that would cause it to turn off when the screen is closed. Also you might go to the Power Mode settings and set them to always optimize performance, although I would not automatically think this to be a problem. I'm not authoritative on this, but may give you something to try. Report back with the results.

Comment: When I close the laptop, the external monitor is getting black. I set the option to not go to power safe mode when closing the laptop. My expectation would be, that the external monitor operates as single monitor. Will try your hints.